# no factors in the fitted model In addition: Warning messages: 1: In replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf) : non-factors ignored:how to solve?

Tags: r

anova2 <- aov(strength ... + marble:scoria:Age, data = anova)
TukeyHSD(anova2)
no factors in the fitted model
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf) :
  non-factors ignored:

how to solve this problem please to get post hoc?

Comment: Are your independent variables actually categorical? If yes, ensure that they are factors before fitting the model. If no, ..., well, then your question doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: Thanks i get by using factors..another question, i have three factors strength, workability and cost for 10 different mix and i want to select one mix which has high strength, less cost and workable mix how am i going to do this on Rstudio?